# How to modify Mailchimp Subscriber Pop-up (embed) cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

The default expiration time is 1 year.I want 1 Week.

The embed code is this one.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js

How to do this

```
    if(document.cookie.indexOf("MCEvilPopupClosed") > 0 ){

    //check if (Cookie was created more than 7 days){delete cookie} 

    }
```